# Writing FileSystemObject in Excel 2013 VBA does not work anymore

Tags: vba, excel

In Excel 2013 VBA this code runs, but does not write a file and does not output any errors.  I have Microsoft Scripting Runtime enabled.

Do I need to qualify class names?  What am I missing?

```
Set fs = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
If Not fs.FolderExists(Write_Dir_Name) Then
   Create_Directory Write_Dir_Name
End If
If Right(Write_File_Name, 4) = ".xml" Then
   Set a = fs.CreateTextFile(Write_File_Name, True)
Else
   Set a = fs.CreateTextFile(Write_File_Name & ".xml", True)
End If

'...    
'Writes data to xml file
'...

a.Close
```

Comment: Double check the values of `Write_Dir_Name` and `Write_File_Name`. I understand those are variable?

Comment: Yes, those are variables.  I checked and set the variables to Write_Dir_Name = "C:\TEMP\" and Write_File_Name="test.xml".  C:\TEMP\ exists.  test.xml does not get created.

Comment: Likely the file is getting created, but justnot where you're looking for it. You're only specifying a file name when calling `CreateTextFile`, so it will end up in whatever is the Current Directory. Use a full path to prevent confusion.

Comment: @TimWilliams good tip!  After searching, these files are somehow getting created in C:\Users\<username>\Documents

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Likely the file is getting created, but just not where you're looking for it.

You're only specifying a file name when calling CreateTextFile, so it will end up in whatever is the Current Directory.

Use a full path to prevent confusion:

```
Set fs = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
If Not fs.FolderExists(Write_Dir_Name) Then
   Create_Directory Write_Dir_Name
End If
If Right(Write_File_Name, 4) = ".xml" Then
   Set a = fs.CreateTextFile(Write_Dir_Name & Write_File_Name, True)
Else
   Set a = fs.CreateTextFile(Write_Dir_Name & Write_File_Name & ".xml", True)
End If

'...    
'Writes data to xml file
'...

a.Close
```